# AS 3 | Fade-In and Fade-Out loop | ENTER_FRAME

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

I'm building a basic kids app for iOS and I want to fade-in and fade-out my background to sync with my sun and moon animation.

The problem is, my fade-in and fade-out code, has a lower value of 0.01 and still too fast for my app, I want a slow fade animation, like 0.001 but it's not working with this values.

```
bgLight.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeout);

function fadeout(e:Event){
    if(bgLight.alpha <=0){
        bgLight.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeout);
        bgLight.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadein);
    } else {
        bgLight.alpha -=.01; // That's the small value
    }
}

function fadein(e:Event){
    if(bgLight.alpha >= 1){
        bgLight.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadein);
        bgLight.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeout);
    } else {
        bgLight.alpha +=.01; // That's the small value
    }
}
```

Is it possible the reach a small value like 0.001 using ENTER_FRAME?
My project has 60 FPS.

Comment: you typically do that with a Tween engine like this one: http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

Comment: Yeah you want to use tweens.  Here's a tutorial regular flash tween code: [http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3tweenclass/](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3tweenclass/) .  If you need to do anything more than a simple tween to one thing, use greensock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, actually I'm using now the Greensock engine for this basic tween. 
It's very easy to use, and I think will use less CPU usage.

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

TweenMax.to(bgLight, 35.5, {alpha:0, repeatDelay:1, repeat:-1, yoyo:true});
```

Thanks for your time guys.